# How to create a new Dataframe column from a list. Pd series not working

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I need to perform a calculation on a dataframe iterating over rows. For each row, the output is appended to a list and then the list is used to create a Dataframe column:

```
lis123 = []
...for loop on df... rate is the output value for each row
list123.append(rate)
df['new column'] = list123
```

doing like this I get error:
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

so I tried to convert list to series doing this:

`df['new column'] = pd.Series(list123)`

however, if I convert the list to a Series, not all of the values are picked up...for some rows, the new column is just empty. This shouldn't be the case, because I tried to perform same calculation processing single rows and all of them produce values.

I would really appreciate your help in understanding what I missing or doing wrong

thanks!

Comment: please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question

Comment: You should provide more code. There could be many reasons why you're not getting the behaviour you expect. For now though, have you tried to look at the list you generate in the for loop and see that its length and values are as expected?

Comment: Are you sure you iterate on rows and not on columns?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  2
1  1  8  9
2  3  9  1
3  6  2  4
4  9  1  4

>>> df.shape
(5, 3)
```

You can iterate over it in several ways:

```
# Over columns
>>> for i in df: print(f"{i}")
A
B
C

# Over rows
>>> for idx, sr in df.iterrows(): print(f"{idx}:\n{sr}\n")
0:
A    1
B    2
C    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64

1:
A    1
B    8
C    9
Name: 1, dtype: int64
...

# Over rows
>>> for row in df.itertuples(): print(f"{row}")
Pandas(Index=0, A=1, B=2, C=2)
Pandas(Index=1, A=1, B=8, C=9)
Pandas(Index=2, A=3, B=9, C=1)
Pandas(Index=3, A=6, B=2, C=4)
Pandas(Index=4, A=9, B=1, C=4)
```

You can convert the output of your loop into a new column only on the two last methods.